# Как преобразовать картинки в data set?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

У меня есть 2 вида картинок.
Первая это скриншот с видео.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вторая это скриншот консоли в которой этот скриншот отрисован символами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оба изображения имеют размер 640х360.

Всего имеется 5к картинок 2х версия, 10к в общем. 
Я усредню каждый пиксель (R+G+B) / 3, получу оттенок. Во втором скриншоте беру G канал так как там только зеленый цвет.

В итоге я получаю 2 массива чисел. 230400 параметров. Мне уже что то подсказывает что обучать такую сеть я буду лет 50. Думаю объединить пиксели в квадраты по 100шт и взять среднее значение для них.
Проблема в том что я не знаю как это все скомпоновать?
До этого ML я трогал через Model Builder в Net, там все просто, загрузил табличку, выбрал столбец который надо спрогнозировать. А мне надо спрогнозировать каждый пиксель.

Вопрос состоит в том как из всего этого создать Data Set который можно будет обработать нейронкой?
В итоге хочу получить модель которая стилизирует картинку под ASCII графику.

Comment: `(R+G+B) / 3` - это вы яркость пикселя получаете, а не оттенок )